# Save session variables are overwritten

Tags: php, session-variables

I ask the user how many times he would like to roll dices.
And the script reveals the output.

```
session_start();
$number = $_POST["dice"]; // capture the amount of rolls from htmlpage
$count1 = 0; //have six of these, for each number
```

I then proceed to initalise the session variables that are stored serverside.

```
$_SESSION["one"] = $count1; // for all six different numbers

echo "You rolled a 1 " . $_SESSION["one"] . " times<br>";
```

My problem is naturally that the session variable does not store the old rolls, but resets at each roll. How can I go about to change this?

I reckon I need to something like `isset(_SESSION["one"]` but here my logic gives up on me. Any help appreciated.

Comment: `if( isset($var) && !empty($var)) { // set var }`

Comment: Can you explain better what you're trying to achieve? May be able to help better. Some sort of output per roll etc.

Comment: Exactly how will increment the already set variable?

Comment: Use an array if you want to store multiple rolls.

Comment: @droppyboxi please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I re-read your question:

```
<?php
session_start();

$number_of_rolls = $_POST['dice'];

for($i = 0; $i <= $number_of_rolls; ++$i)
{
    $roll_result = roll_dice_algorithm();
    $_SESSION['rolls'][$roll_result] = (isset($_SESSION['rolls'][$roll_result]) ? ($_SESSION['rolls'][$roll_result]+1) : 1);
}

ksort($_SESSION['rolls']);

foreach($_SESSION['rolls'] as $k=>&$v)
{
    echo 'You have rolled a '.$k.': '.$v.' times<br>';
}
unset($v);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You said it yourself, you intialize the session variables every times you run your script...

```
$_SESSION["one"] = $count1; // for all six different numbers
```

So it will always start over... Try this instead

```
$_SESSION["one"] = isset($_SESSION["one"]) ? $_SESSION["one"] : 0;
```